# Adding a custom data layer to the OSM ID Editor on a private server

Tags: openstreetmap, id-editor

How to add a custom map layer on a locally installed ID Editor on a private server?

There is an option "Custom Map Data" available, but it is only valid for the current session i.e. after closing the browser tab, the created map is deleted. However, in this case, a permanent custom map is needed.

It means to add one layer below the "OpenStreetMap Data" in the image below.

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend using JOSM instead of iD if you want to import custom data from an external source.

Comment: @Berrely: I need a web-based solution, so different remote users can work on creating a new map without using a software.